# how to install xubuntu 13.04 theme to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: themes

i would like to know how to install default xubuntu theme along with xubuntu default icon to Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a theme just copy your extracted theme to ~/.themes
or for your icons ~/.icons.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Hugh! The question specifically asks how to install the default Xubuntu theme to Ubuntu, and not a generic "how do I install a theme" question. I doubt that he has the theme.